# Tampermonkey - How to set text in the google search box?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How can i set some text in the google search box with tampermonkey?

I have tried the following but no text is set:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Search Test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Testing selectors.
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.co.uk*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var textinput = document.querySelector('input.gsfi[type=text]');
    textinput.value = "Cats";
})();
```

Comment: There is a library called [***ArriveJS***](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) which will watch for DOM element creation and removals. You can just listen for that selector to appear on the page.

Comment: Thanks, that library looks useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is correct. You can simply check this by typing the code `document.querySelector('input.gsfi[type=text]')` into the JavaScript console. It should show the correct element.

The problem with the Google website is that the class of the input element is added after the Tampermonkey function is called (maybe trough some JavaScript).

So a workaround could be to check the input element after a short interval:

```
function test() {
    var textinput = document.querySelector('input.gsfi[type=text]');
    if (textinput!==null)
        textinput.value = "Cats";
    else
        console.log("textinput is null");
}

(function() {
    'use strict';
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: Instead of dying on `null`, you could have a limit on how many times the timeout is called and just keep calling it over and over until the limit is reached.

Comment: Perfect, it works great, i will accept this answer when it lets me. It should be !== by the way as it suggested there was an error in the editor.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait for the element to arrive. Just pass in a limit and the number of ms you will wait between each check.

```js
function onArrival(selector, callback, interval, limit) {
  interval = interval || 1000; // Default wait time is 1 second.
  limit = limit || 10;         // Default number of attempts is 10.
  var el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el != null) {
    if (callback != null) {
      callback(el);
    }
  } else {
    if (limit > 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        onArrival(selector, callback, interval, limit - 1);
      }, interval);
    } else {
      console.log('Element not found!');
    }
  }
}

// Wait 3 seconds to load the input element.
setTimeout(function() {
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.innerHTML = 'Google Search: ';
  document.body.appendChild(label);
  
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.className = 'gsfi';
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}, 3000);

// Wait 5 times, 1 second at a time, for the input element to arrive.
onArrival('input[type="text"].gsfi', function(el) {
  el.value = 'Cats';
}, 1000, 5)
```

Comment: I have accepted an answer but thanks this looks really useful

Comment: I'm trying to paste data already in the clipboard into search and clicking the search button. Do you have tips on how `el.value = 'Cats';` could be tweaked to accomodate this? There must another question that does what I want?